# How does OkHttp handle non-matching domains with cert pinning?

Tags: okhttp, certificate-pinning

Let's say I pin a cert for a specific domain:

```
CertificatePinner certPinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add("*.domain1.com", CertificatePinner.pin(...))
    .build()
                
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .certificatePinner(certPinner)
    .build
```

How does OkHttp handle requests to **other** domains (e.g. `api.domain2.com`)?

- "No matching cert, no bueno --> SecurityException"
- "No matching cert, no problemo `++` --> completes request"

`++` provided domain2's cert is still signed by C.A. listed in OS-level list of trusted authorities.

Answer (score 1):

- "No matching cert, no problemo ++ --> completes request"

Certificate pinning adds a constraint for matching hosts only.